# assign different number for array index in Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to assign a different number to the indexes of my array without modifying the array. for example on my code it prints Salesperson 0, Salesperson 1, etc as it gets the index ID of the array in my code. what i'm trying to achieve is that the information of Salesperson 1 be assigned to the index 0 on my array so that it doesn't display as Salesperson 0 on my output.

here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Sales {

public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        //part where program asks how many persons to compute
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of Salesperson: ");
        int SALESPEOPLE = scan.nextInt();

        //part where variables are declared
        int[] sales = new int[SALESPEOPLE];
        int sum;
        float ave;
        int max_sales=0;
        int max_person=0;
        int min_sales=0;
        int min_person=0;


            //part where values for sales are asked and  entered
        for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter sales for salesperson "+i+": ");
                sales[i]=scan.nextInt();

            //part where sales are compared to find the minimum and maximum sales
                if (i == 0)
                    {
                        min_sales = sales[i];
                        max_sales = sales[i];
                    }
                if (sales[i] > max_sales)
                    {
                        max_sales = sales[i];
                        max_person = i;
                    }
                if (sales[i] < min_sales)
                    {
                        min_sales=sales[i];
                        min_person=i;
                    }
            }

        System.out.println("\nSalesperson           Sales");
        System.out.println("-----------         --------");
        sum=0;
        ave=0;

            //part where the sales are displayed
        for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("    "+i+"                "+money.format(sales[i]));
                sum += sales[i];
                ave = sum/SALESPEOPLE;
            }
        System.out.println("\nTotal sales "+money.format(sum));
        System.out.println("Average sales "+money.format(ave));
        System.out.println("Salesperson "+min_person+" had the highest sale with "+money.format(min_sales));
        System.out.println("Salesperson "+max_person+" had the highest sale with "+money.format(max_sales));
    }


}
```

Comment: Not clear to me what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I agree with Dici in that I don't quite get your question. If it's just printing 1 instead of 0 etc. you might just add 1 to `i` when printing or iterate from  `i = 1` to `i = sales.length` and subtract 1 from `i` when accessing the array.

Comment: I stopped reading at you want to change a value in an array without modifying the array

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  Do you actually want everything shifted (so that there is nothing in `sales[0]`) or do you just want it to print out starting at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @phflack - nothing was attempted, but I see what you're saying - "here's what I'm thinking, how can I do it that way"

Comment: i attempted doing what phflack was saying that i shifted the values of the indexes to index 1.
`for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)`
but that was not what i was trying to achieve. 
the way i did it is i added 1 on the output here `System.out.print("Enter sales for salesperson "+i+": ");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just change what you are printing

```
System.out.print("Enter sales for salesperson "+(i+1)+": ");
```

Also, this line

```
System.out.println("    "+(i+1)+"                "+money.format(sales[i]));
```

Also you duplicate the highest sales string in your output at the end

Other than that, I don't see any problems with your code

Comment: this is what i was looking to achieve. i didn't even try this. i had doubts that it would destroy the code entirely. Thank you very much. also to @Thomas for the help.

Comment: You probably want to change the text that prints out the results so it matches ("part where the sales are displayed".)  Should have a i+1 in there too:
System.out.println("    " + (i + 1) +"                "+money.format(sales[i]));

Comment: @JessereeJoMancera How could a println break a whole code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the indexes of an array. But if you want to change the output in a way that you print salesperson0 when you access the 1 index of your array you can just do what Thomas said.

Answer (score -2):

- save the array values in another array, swap them
- define a rule for the indexes... maybe you could create a function for the array which returns value at index x if you provide index y....

Comment: All the question is asking for is so it "doesn't display as Salesperson 0 on my output"